# Laravel - Model Default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, model, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a table like it-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFHSP.png

And model for it is like this-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WebinarLiveAttenders extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'webinar_live_attenders';
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable = array('webinar_id','ip','last_update');
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function webinars()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Webinar');
    }
}
```

I am running a query like this-

```
public function post_update_user_status()
{
    //Request::getClientIp();
    $requestData = Request::all();
    $date = new DateTime;
    $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $user_status = WebinarLiveAttenders::firstOrNew([
                                                        'webinar_id' => $requestData['uuid'],
                                                        'ip'         => Request::getClientIp()
                                                    ]);
    $user_status->last_update = $formatted_date;
    $user_status->save();
    return 'Done';
}
```

Problem is I am getting **time_on**=0 always.

But I want it to be the time of creation.

I can't use timestamps here.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why cant you use timestamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to put `time_on` in,

`protected $fillable = array('webinar_id','ip','last_update', 'time_on');`

I suggest you use this fields `created_at` `updated_at` and `deleted_at` for `softDelete()`.

Its like, `Laravel` will know what are you talking about, and turn things simple for you.

it should be:

`protected $fillable = array('webinar_id','ip','created_at' 'updated_at', 'deleted_at');`

keep this in mind in future webapps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set the `time_on` to the formatted date.
You can check the `$user_status->exists` for existance in database.

```
if(!$user_status_>exists) {
  // First creation of user_status, so lets set a creation_date
  $user_status->time_on = $formatted_date;
}
$user_status->last_updated = $formatted_date;
$user->save();
```